# next.js socket.io useeffect not updating on socket message

Tags: sockets, socket.io, react-hooks, next.js, react-context

i'm facing an issue with my socket client on next.js . i have created a context for providing my socket instance for all components in the application , the problem is that when i want to use the socket context on my component i am using the useeffect hook be called once the socket is changed and i will handle on message call ( like any tutorial i have seen on the web ) but with new message on the socket the useeffect is not called at all . for those who may think this is context issue i should say its not i have tested socket initiation  on the component itslef and still useeffect not being called .
here is the way im using the socket instance :

```
export default function MyComp(props){
    const cookies = new Cookies()
    const token = cookies.get('token');
    const socket = io(routes.socket_url, { path: '/socket',
        transports: ['websocket'],
        query:{
        token,
        user_id:'someuserid'
    } 
    });

   useEffect(() => {
        console.log('socket changed');
        console.log(socket);
        console.log('socket changed');
   },[socket])
}
```

i can actually see the connection on my devtools and also see the message in the network tab so it means we have a connection (also checked on server ) but the console.log() part is never called on new messages .

and here is my component using the context .

```
export default function MyComp(props){
   const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
   useEffect(() => {
        console.log('socket changed');
        console.log(socket);
        console.log('socket changed');
   },[socket])
}
```

the connection in  this one is also available in the devtools and it gets the new message on networks tab but the logging is never called in useeffect .

thank you for any help .

Comment: The second parameter in a `useEffect` call is a dependency *array*. Try changing it to `[socket]`.

Comment: thank you  . its actually my mistake . still the useffect not working as expected .

Comment: Not sure your socket implementation is correct, might be worth having a look at https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/#socketio-react-and-nodejs-implementing-the-react-client.

Answer (score 2):

guys i found the answer . i was using socket.io-client v 3.1.1  and i started testing other versions . for some strange reason
in version 3 socket instance is not receiving any messages though the connection is already stablished and i can see the messages coming in the networks tab .
anyways i changed version from 3 to 2.1.1 and its working like a charm .